# Bugzilla to Jira? Twiki to Confluence?

Tags: bug-tracking, jira

I am looking into migrating from Bugzilla to Jira and from Twiki to Confluence.

Few questions I have are...

- Feasibility?
- How risky is it?
- How large of project would these be?

I am not too familiar with this yet and anything will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlassian tools have some built-in importers for just this case, and they're pretty good. I've also done a dozen or so commercial migrations and they often turn out to be bigger than one might expect due to multiple iterations on getting the mapping right, unicode chars in the input (e.g. cut and paste from Word documents) and other pains.

~Matt